# Git: How to get a specific version of a file from its .gitattributes ident?

Tags: git, gitattributes, ident

I have some Python scripts that have an $Id$ field set by .gitattributes at checkout.  How can I use this ident string to check out (or otherwise identify) the specific version of the file?

The problem arises when a client uses a script, but isn't sure which version they've checked out.  It would be nice to just ask for the $Id: ... $ and see which version they're using.

Answer (score 0):

The string after $id: is the SHA of the contents of the file. So you can simply do:

```
git show <SHA>
```

which will show you the contents of the file identified by SHA.